# How can i test my expo app in bare workflow on IOS device?

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, expo

I just ejected my Expo app to access to in app purchase feature. But i don't know how to test my app on a physical apple device to test my IAP feature (without test flight because i want to see my logs to debug more easly).
Is there a way for that ?

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can try `expo run:ios -d`?
`-d` allows you to choose one of your connected devices :)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thank you =)

Comment: Can you put it as the accepted answer? :)

Comment: I'm not OP, so I can't seem to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use these alternatives:

1- [Lumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)

CocoaLumberjack is a fast & simple, yet powerful & flexible logging framework for macOS, iOS, tvOS and watchOS.

2- [LibComponentLogging](https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-Core/)

LibComponentLogging is a small logging library for Objective-C on Mac OS X and iOS which provides log levels, log components, and pluggable logging back-ends, e.g. writing log messages to a file, or sending them to the system log.

3- [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)

NSLogger is a high performance logging utility which displays traces emitted by client applications running on macOS, iOS and Android. It replaces traditional console logging traces (NSLog(), Java Log).

The NSLogger Viewer runs on macOS and replaces Xcode, Android Studio or Eclipse consoles. It provides powerful additions like display filtering, defining log domain and level, image and binary logging, message coloring, traces buffering, timing information, link with source code, etc.