# iOS/Expo: Can't build on physical device after ejecting to bare workflow

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I just ejected my project to a bare workflow and I am unable to build my project to my physical device (iPhone SE gen 2). It builds normally to the iOS simulator for every device type.

When I run `expo run:ios -d`, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329378/how-can-i-test-my-expo-app-in-bare-workflow-on-ios-device) points out, my device is not listed in the options list. On the Xcode UI, my device **is** shown, but it immediately says the build fails when I try to run my app (other sims work fine here too). I've tried the posts I've found across different forums (cleaning builds etc) but nothing seems to work. For context, I am running on a m1 mac.

Any guidance here would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I did not have a developer account associated with the project in Xcode. Once adding one and registering my device, I was able to build it onto my device